# How to stop Blender animation render in the middle of the rendering process?

Tags: rendering, animation, cycles-render-engine, workflow

What I mean by "in the middle of the rendering process", let's pretend that I have an animation of 100 frames and when the render process is at frame 50, how can I stop the rendering when the frame 50 is done?

*Note:* I'm using Cycles for rendering.

Comment: Close it or just press ESC.

Comment: You should've post this as an answer not a comment! But anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Pressing** <kbd>ESC</kbd> **will stop the rendering process.**

However, if you are saving your render as a video file format your video may not be playable. In this case, I would recommend changing the render output file format to an image sequence like "JPG", "PNG" or "EXR". This will save every single frame as an image. You can then use Blender's video editor (or any other third-party video editor) to add an image sequence and render out the video in the desired format.

**Set the end frame.**

If you already know beforehand that you only want to render 50 frames it is easier to just set the end frame to 50. That way you don't have to intervene manually.

Comment: Thanks Sebastian for the information, I'm using OpenEXR format as an output file format.
Closing the render window or pressing ESC does the job.

Comment: You're welcome, Ali! It works the same for OpenEXR. If this answered your question then please mark it as accepted.

Comment: `Esc` will only stop the render. but the denoising cannot be stopped. this is a known bug i think? on blender 3.3.1

Answer (score 2):

You can get something close. If using cycles, set the time or sample limit to something short (e.g. 4 seconds). The setting will apply and the render will finish quickly (the later parts will be low quality, but you were planning on cutting them out anyway so that shouldn't matter much to you).